# As it is not possible to "pause" Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, is there any alternative to avoid being charged?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I already have my hosting, but I want to test and play with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for a while.

As I don't have the free tier anymore, I want to be careful to pay as little as I can.

So, I thought on creating an environment and adding to it my app, testing it, and after that somewhat "pause" it, in order to not get charged (some charges are per hour that the environment is up).

**But I've realised that you cannot do any pause. Either your environment is up, or you just terminate it.**

Is there any other way? Maybe a snapshot?

**What am I going to be charged in that case? Just the space that the snapshot occupy in memory like a file added to S3?**

In the snapshot case, may I restore it with **all the information?** (database, files, configuration, etc?).

Thanks for your insight, as Amazon docs isn't clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the configuration of your environment and then terminate it, then create new environments from that configuration. That would avoid most of the charges and create an identical environment.

BUT that won't keep your database, only the environment configuration. You still need to snapshot your database to restore from that.

In this case, you would incur charges for the versions stored in S3 and database snapshots (see the pricing pages for [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing) and [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing) for details). But no charges for EC2 instances or ELB, as the environment is terminated.